# Sqlite data saving error

Tags: iphone, sqlite, blob

My code is:

```
const char *sqlInsertString;
sqlite3_stmt *addStatement;
sqlInsertString=sqlite3_mprintf("insert into AnimalTable(name,propertyID,animalID,breed,dateofbirth,sex,notes,imageData) values" "('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d')",nameString,propertyString,animalidString,breedString,dateofbirth,sexString,notesString,imageData);
    if (sqlite3_open([sqlFile UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsertString, -1, &addStatement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(addStatement)==SQLITE_DONE) {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(addStatement, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], NULL);
            sqlite3_finalize(addStatement);
            NSLog(@"Data saved");

        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Some Error occurred");
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
```

I guess I am doing something wrong, cant figure it out.
Its showing  some error occurred msg, whenever i add data to sqlite.
And also getting exception NSInternalInconsistencyException no such table:AnimalTable.
But AnimalTable exist and when i execute the query in sqlmanager it runs properly.

Comment: offtopic: please use for future projects FMDatabase: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is use for the storing the blob type of data store,

May this helping to you

```
 if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsertQry, -1, &compiledStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ){
                for (NSDictionary *dObj in arForData) {
                     sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStmt,1,[[dObj valueForKey:@"NotiData"] bytes],[[dObj valueForKey:@"NotiData"] length],NULL);
                    PUT_Date(2,@"fireDate");


                    NSUInteger err = sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
                    if (err != SQLITE_DONE){
                        //NSLog(@"error while binding %d %s",err, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                        //NSLog(@"%@",dObj);
                    }
                    sqlite3_reset(compiledStmt);
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);     
            }
```